# I want to search data in csv file where data is taken from file1.csv and searching in file2.csv in using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a list of data in file1.csv(contains more than 1000 lines), using that data I have to search in file2.csv(contains more than 1700 lines) and marked as true if data is found in file1.csv also, I am new to python appreciate if anybody help me.

file1.csv

```
qwee
asdf
erttg
hrthr
rthtr
tjes
tykiut
fdh
yukyu
```

file2.csv

```
fdh
gryj
uilyh
hrthr
yuhh
ljjj
qwee
erttg
rthtr
```

Output:

```
fdh     TRUE
gryj    FALSE
uilyh   FALSE
hrthr   TRUE
yuhh    FALSE
ljjj    FALSE
qwee    FALSE
erttg   TRUE
rthtr   TRUE



import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = 'file2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)


found = df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('hrthr').any(), axis=1)
print(found)
```

I am getting below output:

```
0       False
1        True
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...
1754    False
1755    False
1756    False
1757    False
1758    False
Length: 1759, dtype: bool
```

Comment: are there repeated values in the `file2`?

Comment: there would be no repeated values in file2.

Comment: @Yuca thanks for helping!

Comment: my answer works! ignore previous msg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way is just to check if col values in df1 is present in the values of the df2:

**Recreate datasets**

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['qwee'],['asdf'],['erttg'],['hrthr'],
    ['rthtr'],['tjes'],['tykiut'],['fdh'],
    ['yukyu']], columns=['col1']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['fdh'],['gryj'],['uilyh'],['hrthr'],
    ['yuhh'],['ljjj'],['qwee'],['erttg'],
    ['rthtr']], columns=['col2']
)
```

**Solution**

```py
df1['check'] = df1.col1.isin(df2.col2)

Out[1]:
    col1    check
0   qwee    True
1   asdf    False
2   erttg   True
3   hrthr   True
4   rthtr   True
5   tjes    False
6   tykiut  False
7   fdh     True
8   yukyu   False
```

**Added**: Given you have quite a bit of rows, performance is not an issue:

```py
%timeit df1['check'] = df1.col1.isin(df2.col2)

# 183 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I am able to see the correct output but I am not getting output as yours i.e. col1 is not printing.

Comment: Interesting, could be due to col / values format. I will update the answer to show how i recreated the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df2['check'] = [df1[0].str.contains(x).any() for x in df2[0].values]
```

Output

```
       0  check
0    fdh   True
1   gryj  False
2  uilyh   True
3  hrthr   True
4   yuhh   True
5   ljjj  False
6   qwee  False
7  erttg   True
8  rthtr  False
```